# Artisan pass url as parameter from git bash

Tags: php, laravel, git-bash, laravel-artisan

I have following ScrapeSite Artisan command.

```
class ScrapeSite extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'scrape:site
                            {url : The url to parse}';

    protected $description = 'Scrape site';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $url = $this->argument('url');
        echo $url;
    }
}
```

When I call `php artisan scrape:site http://example.com` from Git Bash, the output is: `http:\example.com`. I also tried: `php artisan scrape:site 'http://example.com'` and `php artisan scrape:site "http://example.com"`, but the result is the same.

But I want it to be `http://example.com`. If I use cmd.exe, the output is as expected.

If I run following bash script `./script.sh http://example.com`, the output is as expected: `http://example.com`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $1
```

windows7, php7, laravel 5.2, Git for Windows v2.6.4

Comment: Try escaping the slash characters like this `php artisan scrape:site "http:\/\/example.com"`

Comment: I tried, but result is still the same: `http:\example.com`.